# Is there an anti virus that protects processes from being injected code to?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, password-policy

As title says, is there an av that does that?

And if not, is there any other program that protects processes like lsass in windows, apart from protected process utility in win8.1?

Comment: Have you looked at any of these products? As far as I know, most anti-virus software has this protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most antivirus will *try* to protect processes from code injection. However, this is ultimately heuristic: the only clear distinction between malicious code injection, and normal process behaviour, is at the human level: did the human user actually wanted that to happen, or not. Software in general, AV in particular, cannot fathom the intricate psychological processes in the soul of the human user.

So AV software commonly relies on recognizing known "hostile payload" and tries to catch variants thereof. It is a delicate compromise between security and functionality: the AV should let the normal data flow, but still reliably locate and destroy maliciously crafted data. So AV vendors must tap-dance between false positives (blocking normal data, thus breaking functionality) and false negatives (failing to block malicious data). Furthermore, AV ought to be efficient: they cannot afford to use all the CPU resources of the machine in order to come to a block/pass decision.

Common AV surveys all network communications to apply their automatic filters on all data flows. Some also try to be especially careful and strict for data which flows to specific, "sensitive" process like, indeed, lsass.exe.

**Summary:** yeah, AV do that. But don't expect miracles.